# cannot find the reference string in ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg

Im trying to obtain a serial key for a downloader manager.
Im using ollydbg to get it and follow the tips mentioned in youtube.

I looked for the reference string that matches "30 days" because whenever I try to install 
this app it always say that the trial period is only "30 days" and I need to have the serial number to be able to use it. Unfortunately, that string is nowhere to be found.

The question is, is there any other way to look for that string? if there's no way, why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this site is not for hacking/cracking. Moderators can delete your question regarding to steal others work or use free for paid apps.
**This was my notice**. 
And for your question, not all applications store their constant strings in the executable. Some of these maybe using `registery`, or any special `file` or other `modules`/dlls to store strings and load these strings dynamically at run time. If you smart enough you can find the binding/loading/reading places at looking/following the execution in the Olly. This is the hardest part.
And there is more. Even you find the string, you have to make sure that `30` regards the remaining time. You can change it but no luck, because under the hood there are more controls, register operations to check the limiting interval.